# Cannot create user in database: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to add an user to the database file but i get the following error when trying to create an User object:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class Patient->patient'. Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Patient.documents - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from forms import LoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'SECRETKEY'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///storage.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

"""
Users
"""
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    mail = db.Column(db.String, default='test@mail')
    role = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.name}')"


"""
Patients
"""
class Patient(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    prename = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    mail = db.Column(db.String, default='test@mail')
    birthdate = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    documents = db.relationship('Doc', backref='patient', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Patient('{self.prename}', '{self.name}')"


"""
Documents
"""
class Doc(db.Model):
    from datetime import datetime

    pdfid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    path = db.Column(db.String)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    deletetime = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    patientid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Docs('{self.path}', '{self.created}')"
```

My Steps in a python Terminal (the file is called index):

1. from index import db
2. db.create_all()
3. from index import User, Doc, Patient
4. user1 = User(name='Test User', username='test', password='testtest', role=1)
5. When I try step 4 I get the above described error.

I don't see any problem in my code so I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: The `ForeignKey` on `Doc` should point to `patient.id`, not `user.id`.

Comment: @SuperShoot Thank you! It was quite a 'hidden' mistake :D